# Safe to remove async when no await's are used?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, async-await

This may seam as a stupid question, but can I remove the `async` function below since there are no `await`'s? It is a part of a large code base that is in production, so I am wondering if there could be some weird side effects if I remove `async`?

```
(async function(){
  'use strict';
  const {appLogger, monitorLogger} = require('./functions/logger');

...

  for (let i in p) {
    p[i].Filename = i;
    check(p[i]);
  }

...
    
  app.get('/example.json', (req, res) => {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(checkStates, null, 4));
  })

  app.listen(port, () => {
    appLogger.info(`Exposing http://localhost:${port}/example.json`);
  })

})();
```

Comment: The only difference in this case is, since `async` function always return a Promise, it returns `Promise<void>` instead of `void`. But either way, you're not interested in the value the function returns. So yeah, just remove the `async`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My only thought would be that the `await` wraps any returned value (that isn't a promise) in a promise. However, this is a self-calling function and from what you've shown us there is nothing returned and nothing expecting a return. So unless there's other code you haven't shown, yes you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in this case you could remove async.

Answer (score 1):

nope you dont need async if you're not awaiting for any promises.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there might be side effects. `async` makes the function returns a promise, and that may have impacts somewhere, there's not always strictly the same behavior before and after removing the async keyword, for example

```
const fn = () => 10
const afn = async () => 10

afn() // a Promise
fn() // a number

afn().then(() => {}) // ok
fn().then(() => {}) // throws :(
```

but in your case, all good, this won't change anything